# android - sending image via intent

Tags: android

Refer [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions) for permission part.

I have the first app which has the following :

```
File imagePath = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "earth.jpg");
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        "com.android.provider.DataSharing", newFile);

getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission("com.android.datasharing_2.app", contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
i.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(i);
```

In the manifest :

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.android.provider.DataSharing"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>

</provider>
```

In the receiving app (com.android.datasharing_2.app) :

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (imageUri != null){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageURI(imageUri);
}
```

I get the following message in Log in receiving app:

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.provider.DataSharing/my_images/earth.jpg

 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:682)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:659)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:399)
```

I am testing using the Genymotion VM. I push the file 'earth.jpg' to the images folder using adb and can see it there.

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the location of the image. To use `files-path`, one needs to put files under files/ directory. So my images/ directory should have been under there, with the pushed file at :

```
app-dir-path/files/images/earth.jpg
```