# android - share image via intent - uri permissions

Tags: android, android-intent

Referring to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24111584/682869).

I want to ask something specific to per-URI permissions. I understand that to send binary data like an image whose URI is held by a provider in your app, two things must be done :

1) Provider should set android:grantUriPermission

2) Uri permissions must be granted either via Intent.setFlags or context.grantUriPermission

I wanted to see the effect when I don't do step 2. My provider is :

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.android.provider.DataSharing"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>

   </provider>
```

App1 sharing the image with App2 does the following :

```
 File imagePath = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "images");
 File newFile = new File(imagePath, "earth.jpg");
 Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        "com.android.provider.DataSharing", newFile);
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
 i.setType("image/jpeg");
 startActivity(i);
```

My receiving app (App2) does :

```
 Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
 if (imageUri != null){
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageURI(imageUri);
 }
```

But somehow even without granting the URI permission through intent or context, I can see the image in App2's image view. I am testing in Android 4.4.

Can someone help me explain this behavior ? What did I do that App2 still has the rights to access the image ?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a `Uri` for which you previously granted permissions?

Comment: @CommonsWare Well I ran 2 tests. First I granted permissions. Then I commented lines of code granting the permissions, and ran apps again from Android studio in genymotion. Does App2 keep the previous granted permission ?

Comment: When you granted the permission, was it with `Context.grantUriPermission()`, or with an Intent flag?

Comment: @CommonsWare I used context's API.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation for FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), `Context.grantUriPermission()`:

> The permission remains in effect until you revoke it by calling
>   revokeUriPermission() or until the device reboots.

However, if you use the Intent flag:

> Permissions granted in an Intent remain in effect while the stack of
>   the receiving Activity is active. When the stack finishes, the
>   permissions are automatically removed.

So it looks like it's the expected behavior (if you're testing with the same image / same Uri).